# Android, calling glRotatef based on geomagnetic sensor

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d

I have an app that renders a cube. I'm kind of new to using openGL for 3d stuff, but essentially what I want is for a corner of my cube to point north at all times, but also orient itself according to the geomagnetic sensor.

That way, when the user has the phone parallel to the ground and faces north, the corner will point "up" on the screen, whereas if the user has the phone upright, the corner will point "away" from the user, toward the back of the phone.

I had no problem writing this in 2d on only one rotational axis so that it would point the corner north if the phone was parallel to the ground.

However, when I made this 3D, two of the axes seem to be working fine, but the axis I worked with the first time doesn't seem to behave the same way.

I use the following code to get the rotation for each:

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0,0,-4); 
    //get target angle
    targetAngle1 = rotationHandler.getRotation1();
    targetAngle2 = rotationHandler.getRotation2();
    targetAngle3 = rotationHandler.

    if (Math.abs(getShortestAngle(targetAngle1, currentAngle)) > 5) //this is to create a 5 degree "dead zone" so the compass isnt shaky
        currentAngle1 = (getShortestAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle1) > 0) ?
        currentAngle+1f : currentAngle-1f; //increase or decrease the current angle to move it towards the target angle

    if (Math.abs(getShortestAngle(targetAngle2, currentAngle2))>5)
        currentAngle2 = (getShortestAngle(currentAngle2, targetAngle2) > 0) ? 
        currentAngle2 + 1f : currentAngle2-1f;

    if (Math.abs(getShortestAngle(targetAngle3, currentAngle3))>5)
        currentAngle3 = (getShortestAngle(currentAngle3, targetAngle3) > 0) ? 
        currentAngle3 + 1f : currentAngle3 - 1f;


    gl.glRotatef(currentAngle, 0, 0, -4);
    gl.glRotatef(currentAngle2, 0, -4, 0); 
    gl.glRotatef(currentAngle3, -4, 0, 0); 
    cube.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

The calls to glRotatef that use currentAngle2 and currentAngle3 seem to rotate the cube on an axis relative to the cube, while the first call seems to rotate it on an axis relative to the screen.  When I comment out any two of the rotation calls, the third works as intended. But I can't seem to figure out how to get them to work together.

---EDIT---

I found that I could get the cube to rotate to almost any position possible even after taking away the first call. So it seems like I'm going to have to come up with an algorithm that will calculate the rotation as appropriate. I honestly don't know if I can do it but I'll post it here if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but it seems to work as long as the phone isn't completely flat.

After changing the model to a rectangular prism, I could approach the problem a little more clearly. I used only the first two axes, and didn't even touch the last axis. I treated the prism like a fighter jet - in order to turn it left or right, I rotated it on its side, then altered the pitch up or down. Then I "un-rotated" it, and altered the pitch again for to point it up or down as appropriate.

```
    public void findTargetRotation(float rotationAngle, float pitchAngle, GL10 gl){
    //first, enable rotation around a vertical axis by rotating on frontBack axis by -90 degrees
    gl.glRotatef(-90, 0, -4, 0);
    //rotate around the leftRight axis by the angle1 amount
    gl.glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0,-4,0);

    //then rotate on frontBack axis by 90 degrees again, to straighten out
    gl.glRotatef(90, 0, -4, 0);
    //lastly, rotate around the leftRight axis to point it up or down
    gl.glRotatef(pitchAngle, -4, 0, 0);
}
```

This seems to work as long as pitchAngle isn't extremely close to or equal to 0. So I just added a little more code to treat it like a 2D object if the pitchAngle is really small.

There's probably a better solution but at least this works.